# Sum of list element in scala is not executable : error. How to fix?

Tags: scala

I am not able to `execute` or **▶ button is not clickable in `intelleiJ` ** the sum function in following two ways. Please help me to identify the mistakes in both.

```
object Main{
  def sum1(xs : List[Int]): Int = {
    xs.filter(_ > 0).sum // am i missing return word here ?
  }
  def sum2(xs: List[Int]): Unit = {
    val mx = xs.filter(_ > 0).sum // is it ok to have return in a variable ?
    println(mx)
  }
  Main.sum1(List(1,2))
  Main.sum2(List(1,2,3,4))
}
```

Comment: you have to specify the entry point with @main annotation : 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html

Comment: Additionally: _"am i missing return word here?"_ no you are not missing it, **Scala** will use the last expression as the return one for a method; the `return` keyword must not be used. - _"is it ok to have return in a variable?"_ not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Intellij, unless you code from within a `Scala Worksheet` where you can execute execute code without an entry point, in any normal application, you require an entry point to your application.

In Scala 2 you can do this in 2 ways. Either define the `main` method yourself inside an `object` definition, which is the conventional way:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // code here
  }
}
```

Or - have your `object` definition extend the `App` trait, which provides the `main` method for you, so you can start writing code directly inside:

```
object Main extends App {
  // code here
}
```

This is a bit cleaner, and one nested-levels less.

In Scala, statements are called *expressions*, because they generally return the value of the last expression, if the last expression is not an assignment. This code:

```
def sum1(xs: List[Int]): Int = 
  xs.filter(_ > 0).sum
```

Is a syntactic sugar for this:

```
def sum1(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  return xs.filter(_ > 0).sum
}
```

Because braces are optional if the code has only 1 expression, and will return the value of the last expression by default. So even though you can write code both ways, you'll get the warning `Return keyword is redundant`, because you'll never need to use it explicitly.

Also, you don't need to write `Main.sum1(...)` from within `Main`. You can omit the object:

```
object Main extends App {
  def sum1(xs: List[Int]): Int =
    xs.filter(_ > 0).sum

  def sum2(xs: List[Int]): Unit = {
    val mx = xs.filter(_ > 0).sum
    println(mx) // 10
  }

  println(sum1(List(1, 2))) // 3
  sum2(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
}
```

For Scala 3, things get simpler. The recommended way is to annotate a method with the [`@main`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html) annotation to mark it as the entry point in your program. This method ca either be defined at the top-level, or inside an `object` definition, and it's name does not matter anymore:

```
@main def hello() = 
  // code here
```

While Scala 3 still supports the `App` trait from Scala 2, it has now become deprecated and it's functionality has been limited, so if your program needs to cross-build between both Scala 2 and Scala 3 versions, it’s recommended to stick with the basic way of explicitly define a `main` method inside an `object` definition with an `Array[String]` argument instead:

```
object MyMain:
  def main(args: Array[String]) = 
    // code here
```

**Note**, curly braces become optional in Scala 3 in favor of the cleaner Python-style indentation.

Comment: warning, this is a scala 2 only solution

Comment: added scala 3 solution